# Why maven-failsafe plugin not picking integration tests

Tags: maven-3

I configured the maven-failsafe-plugin to run the tests under my integration package.

Here is the code

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${itCoverageAgent} -Xmx1024m</argLine>
                    <skipITs>${skipIT}</skipITs>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/integration/**</include>
                    </includes>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But this is no picking the tests under integration package.

Below is the response from maven-failsafe-plugin

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:integration-test (default) @ mds-core ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
```

But the same configuration is working in another module. Not able to get the cause for this.
Please help me.

Comment: What is the structure of your project? Failsafe plugin looks for classes in `src/test/java`.

Comment: Yes. My all test classes are available in src/test/java only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have below artifacts dependencies

```
junit-platform-runner,
junit-platform-suite-api,
junit-platform-launcher,
```

After commenting these dependencies, it is picking the integration tests.